# Database Backup Robocopy

Tags: sql, backup, robocopy

I have job that runs every 15 minutes that uses robocopy to copy a backup of the tranaction logs to a different server. This job is failing USER has full access rights to both home folder and the destination folder.

JOB SQL:

robocopy "e:\Backup\SQL02$PROD" 
"\SERVER\DRIVE$\prod\sql\backup\" /MIR /E /Z /NS /NFL /NDL /NJH /NP /R:10 /W:30 
if %errorlevel% LSS 8 set errorlevel=0

Error Log:

Date  22/06/2010 09:05:00
Log  Job History (Sync Production backup to app040)

Step ID  1
Server  NDAHHSQL02\PRODUCTION
Job Name  Sync Production backup to app040
Step Name  robocopy production
Duration  00:00:00
Sql Severity  0
Sql Message ID  0
Operator Emailed
Operator Net sent
Operator Paged
Retries Attempted  0

Message
Executed as user: DOMAIN\USER. 2010/06/22 09:05:00

ERROR 5 (0x00000005) Getting File System Type of Destination \\SERVER\DRIVE$\prod\sql\backup\  Access is denied.

2010/06/22 09:05:00 ERROR 5 (0x00000005) Creating Destination Directory \\SERVER\DRIVE$\prod\sql\backup\  Access is denied.  Process Exit Code 16.  The step failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the issue Although the folder had permissions for the account to copy files accross it did not have share permissions set on the root drive.

[Link to share permissions tutorial](http://www.windowsecurity.com/articles/Share-Permissions.html)

Answer (score 0):

The user does not have access to write the backup file to \SERVER\DRIVE$\prod\sql\backup\.

- Should it read \\SERVER?
- You could use NET USE to first mount the server location as a drive and then write to it.
- You could test with some small file instead of a backup

Comment: Sorry that was my editing. 
I have to use robocoy as the Job used to work but now failing.
I will try a test.